# What does enabling coinstatsindex in my bitcoin.conf file do for my node?

Tags: full-node, bitcoin.conf

Using bitcoind --help tells me this:

"Maintain coinstats index used by the gettxoutsetinfo RPC (default: 0)"

Is it just storing the information in `gettxoutsetinfo` for each block in the chain? Just want some more detail about what this means. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is used by the gettxoutsetinfo RPC to provide information about the current UTXO.

it is essentially a database that stores information about each block in the blockchain, including the number of transactions and the total value of outputs in each block. This information is used by the gettxoutsetinfo RPC to provide up-to-date information about the UTXO set.

by default it is not enabled, if you enable it can increase disk space usage and processing time